# Why $(x_2-x_1)^{T}R(x_2-x_1)\ge 0?$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

If we define the space $X, Y\subset \mathbb{R^2}$, define the rotation matrix
$$
  R=\begin{bmatrix}
   \cos\theta &           -\sin\theta \\
    \sin\theta & \cos\theta
  \end{bmatrix}, \theta\in(0, \pi/2).
$$
For $y_i=Rx_i$, $i=1,2$, why
$$(x_2-x_1)\cdot (y_2-y_1)=(x_2-x_1)\cdot (Rx_2-Rx_1)=(x_2-x_1)^{T}R(x_2-x_1)\ge 0?$$

It seems that $(x_2-x_1)\cdot (Rx_2-Rx_1)=0?$

Comment: The inequality in the title is not true if $\cos \theta < 0$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Sorry, $\theta\in(0, \pi/2)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity, let $v = x_2-x_1$.

Intuitively, for any vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $Rv$ rotates the vector $v$ counterclockwise by an angle of $\theta$. So $\|Rv\| = \|v\|$ and the angle between $v$ and $Rv$ is $\theta$. Thus, $v^TRv = \langle v, Rv \rangle = \|v\| \cdot \|Rv\| \cdot \cos\theta = \|v\|^2\cos\theta \ge 0$ for all $\theta \in [0,\tfrac{\pi}{2}]$.

If you need to show this algebraically, let $v = \begin{bmatrix}v_1 & v_2\end{bmatrix}^T$ and try to expand out $$v^TRv = \begin{bmatrix}v_1 & v_2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}v_1 \\ v_2\end{bmatrix} = \cdots$$ and see if you can prove this is non-negative for all $\theta \in [0,\tfrac{\pi}{2}]$.

Comment: Thanks. Is it not zero?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are unit ball $B(0,1)$, is $v^{T}Rv$ zero now?

Comment: You can calculate that $(x_2-x_1)^TR(x_2-x_1) = \|x_2-x_1\|^2\cos\theta$. So unless $\theta = \tfrac{\pi}{2}$ or $x_1 = x_2$, you'll have $(x_2-x_1)^TR(x_2-x_1) > 0$.